# How to use uniqueness existential quantifier for more than one

Tags: predicate-logic

$P(x,y)$ is a predicate function meaning that person $x$ has read person $y$'s book.

Now I want to say there exists only 3 people having read person $t$'s book .

How can I state it with quantifiers?

Is this ok? : $\exists! x\exists! y\exists! z(P(x,t)\land P(y,t)\land P(z,t))$

Comment: $$\exists x \exists y \exists z \Big(x\neq y \land y\neq z \land x\neq z \land P(x, t) \land P(y, t) \land P(z, t) \land \forall q(P(q, t) \to q = x \lor q = y \lor q = z)\Big)$$

Comment: @amWhy Is what I added to my question in recent edit also possible?

Comment: @fmatt, no, as written your statement actually expresses that there is a single person who has read the book.

Comment: fmatt  The uniqueness quantifier designates the existence of one and only one ...  Here we are interested in three, and only three, persons have read t's book.

Comment: @amWhy But doesn't the statement you wrote mean that :" **at least** three different people exist" ??so it isn't three and only three

Comment: Yes it is only three as well, that's where the $\forall q(P(q, t) \to (q=x \lor q=y \lor q = z))$ comes in.  That is, for any q, if q reads t, then q is either x, or y, or z.  We've already established the existence of three readers (x, y, z), and want to rule out all others.

Comment: @amWhy thanks a million devoting your time to help me with my simple question

Comment: Glad to help, @fmatt!!